# Android Developer Sample Code Not Importing Correctly

Tags: java, android, sample, importerror

I have been working with the Android SDK in the Eclipse IDE and have run into a problem with the sample codes provided with the Android SDK.

I am trying to get the Notepad sample code (specifically the NoteEditor) to work and every single import in every class does not work and says that it cannot be resolved to a type.  If I scroll down and import the android.jar file then all of the imports work but the variable R does not.  I cannot find where R is used and don't know exactly what it is.

Does anyone know if I am missing something like a library or why I would need to import android.jar every time.  I would expect these sample projects to work right out of the box so I figured it is something I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the Android Eclipse plugin? http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Please read the Application Resources guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the jar imported. Check the imports at the top of your Activity java file. Make sure that you are not importing {anything}.R Sometimes eclipse like to auto correct imports by importing android.R, or others and that will break your projects references to R's members.

Comment: I had to fix the imports but also I was starting a Java Project and not an Android project.  Intuitive yes I know but I was too used to doing Java projects.

Comment: Also for posterity's sake I had to import the JAR files which is done by right clicking on the project and clicking build path the configure build path and then checking the box for android.jar

Answer (score 0):

Dont import. create new project in workspace from existing sample in eclipse.